# casting json response to object array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, codeigniter, casting

I am trying to learn a bit of angular 2. I am making a simple application to make groups by random order.

I followed the heroes tutorial and the part that is throwing me is where the json response is cast into an object array (Hero[]).

This is the code in the Heroes tutorial (modified to work with my codeigniter backend):

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().heroes as Hero[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and the Hero class:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

This works as expected and I get a list of heroes.

For my own project, this is my version to get my list of groups:

```
getGroups(): Promise<Groupmember[]> {
const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/groups`;

return this.http
  .post(url, JSON.stringify({group_size: '4'}), {headers: this.headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json().groups as Groupmember[])
   .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

My groups class is this:

```
export class Groupmember 
{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  role: string;
  group_id: number;
}
```

The component html is just simple to just show something:

```
<h3>Groups</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let groupmember of groups"  [routerLink]="['/detail', 
      groupmember.id]"  class="col-1-4">
    <div class="module groupmember">
      <h4>{{groupmember.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The actual component (modified dashboard component) is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { Groupmember } from './groupmember';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  groupmembers: Groupmember[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getGroups()
      .then(groupmembers => this.groupmembers = groupmembers.slice(0, 3));
  }
}
```

The model replies with what seems to be the correct data:

```
"groups": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "mr. nice",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "narco",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "bombasto",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "celeritas",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "magneta",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "rubberman",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "dynama",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "dr iq",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "magma",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "tornado",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "name": "mr fantabulous",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "14",
    "name": "xray eyes man",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "name": "new hero",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "name": "old hero",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "name": "another hero",
    "role": "",
    "group_id": "4"
  }
 ]
```

I believe I am doing the exact same method for casting the response into an object array, but it seems not to be casting. There is no data shown in the page Is there something I am missing? I've searched all day trying to find out why this will not work the same. Just seems like I am casting in exactly the same way. Would really appreciate some pointers, especially what is the difference which means that it will work with the heros object but not my groupmember object

Comment: getGroups(): Promise<groupmember[]> { ...    <-- wouldn't this be the same thing? You are putting the URL in this line and not adding the initial array here.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean. I am doing it exactly the same way as worked with the Promise<Hero[]> example. I use the url for other http post which works fine. I am receiving the json, but just cant seem to get the data into Groupmember object form, ie, to cast the json into a groupmember array as is done with the Hero[]

Comment: If you don't know what I mean then why did you modify the exact part I pointed out?getGroups(): Promise { const url = ${this.heroesUrl}/groups; <-- before

getGroups(): Promise<Groupmember[]> { <-- after
const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/groups`;

Comment: In your function you're doing a post. In the original function a get is done. How can you not see these differences?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify what you are pointing to? I do not understand exactly what you are referring to. I only edited because I had not formatted the post right to show the code correctly, so I haven't changed anything other than that. Yes, the post and the get are different. But that should not cause the issue. The data returns correctly. But it is just not casting. I can't see why there would be an affect if it was a post or a get. I can try and change this, but I believe I will just get the same response back.

Comment: I told you that you left out the type in the first cast of groups. You then modified that and claimed you didn't understand what I meant. Now you're even saying that you're doing a post while not managing to understand that a post and a get are two different requests.

Comment: Right, sorry. I think I get you now. When I edited the post is was to fix the fact I haden't editited it right to show the top part of the code correctly. I might have noticed the error and fixed it automatically thinking I jst made a typo. I noticed what you mean and I have got it working. So thank you for your patience and sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Did you get it working by changing it from a get to a post?

Comment: Actually, no, that was ok in the end. I did as you said and also at the same time changed groupmembers to groups. That worked, but I wanted to see if post would both ways (post and get). Both did. So I realised that it was the fact that I was using groups in the service and groupmembers in the dashboard component. I would not have worked that out without your messages as I thought it was ok at first lol.

Comment: Great. Glad it's working!